# select only not empty set on many-to-one relation

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have 3 tables in my database, for example with such names:

```
TableA, TableB, Table_A_B
```

In my mapping file for TableA I have this:

```
<set name="tableBSet" table="Table_A_B" cascade="all" fetch="select" lazy="true">
<key column="tableAId"/>
<many-to-many column="junctionId" class="..."/>
</set>
```

How can I with HQL select only those records, which tableBSet is NOT empty or NOT null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can you provide more mapping or structure ? as far as what you've written , i suggest u want the A's that dont have an empty or null B. so i would say

```
select ab.a 
from tableAB ab 
where (ab.b not null || ab.b not empty)
```

as a pseudo